# Split big bitmap to list of bitmaps in android

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have a big bitmap - sometimes with height 2000 sometimes 4000 etc. This is possible to split this big bitmap dividing by 1500 and save into array?

For example if I have bitmap with height 2300 I want to have array with two bitmaps: one 1500 height and second 800.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`createBitmap()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) to create bitmap chunks from the original `Bitmap`.

The below function takes in a bitmap and the desired chunk size (1500 in your case).
And split the bitmap vertically if the width is greater than height, and horizontally otherwise.

```
fun getBitmaps(bitmap: Bitmap, maxSize: Int): List<Bitmap> {

    val width = bitmap.width
    val height = bitmap.height

    val nChunks = ceil(max(width, height) / maxSize.toDouble())

    val bitmaps: MutableList<Bitmap> = ArrayList()

    var start = 0
    for (i in 1..nChunks.toInt()) {

        bitmaps.add(
            if (width >= height)
                Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, start, 0, width / maxSize, height)
            else
                Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, start, width, height / maxSize)
        )
        start += maxSize
    }

    return bitmaps

}
```

Usage:

```
getBitmaps(myBitmap, 1500)
```

Comment: something wrong is with height. I got height 1 with bitmap size 2300 and max size 1500

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, offsetX, offsetY, width, height);`
to create a "slice" of the bitmap starting at a particular x and y offset, and having a particular width and height.

I'll leave the math up to you.